# Wordpress Woocommerce how to delete image from file system when you delete it in a product

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I have a site where an external API gets products for my Woocommerce shop, and the API sends many images for some products, so I manually go into a product post and delete some of these images.

How can I achieve so that when I do this, these images will be deleted from both media library AND file folder?

I have already figured out how to delete them when I delete the product...

The issue is that I would for example create a product that has 15 images, then delete 5 of them, have the product on my shop for half a year and then delete the product, but then only the 10 images still linked to the product gets deleted and I end up over time having many of unused images...

So how can I permanently delete images when I delete them via the product page in Woocommerce.. (the little cross on the image)

Hope it makes sense :-)

UPDATE:
What I have researched so forth is to get the product image gallery id

Trying

```
add_action ('save_post', 'my_function')
add_action ('woocommerce_update_product', 'my_function')
add_action ('post_updated', 'my_function')
```

My reasoning is to get an array of product image id's from the image gallery both before update and after update and then do an `array_diff()` on those and then do a
`wp_delete_attachment( $delete, $force_delete = true );`
on those, and I have gotten image gallery ids but can't seem to get to having both the old and the new values.

### Working

Read somewhere that the hook **woocommerce_update_product**
actually runs twice, so inspired by another clever little post i used global values to store before and after values :-)

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'action_save_product_data', 10, 2);
    function action_save_product_data( $post_id, $product ) {
         
       // Specify the post type on which to run
       if ( 'product' == get_post_type() )   {
          global $previous_product_id;
          global $before;
          
          if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
             $after = wc_get_product( $post_id )->gallery_image_ids;   
          }
    
          if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
             null;
           }
          else {
             $before = wc_get_product( $post_id )->gallery_image_ids;
          }
    
          if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
             $images_to_be_deleted = array_diff($before, $after);
                foreach($images_to_be_deleted as $delete) {
                   wp_delete_attachment( $delete, $force_delete = true );
                }
          }
          $previous_product_id = $post_id;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Since you got it working, I would recommend creating an answer with your working code. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, and this information may be valuable to future SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working... Some clever global values to remember the values from first run of **woocommerce_update_product**, because of the fact learned elsewhere that it actually runs twice...

Here is the code I got to work :-)

add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'action_save_product_data', 10, 2);
function action_save_product_data( $post_id, $product ) {

```
   // Specify the post type on which to run
   if ( 'product' == get_post_type() )   {
      global $previous_product_id;
      global $before;
      
      if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
         $after = wc_get_product( $post_id )->gallery_image_ids;   
      }

      if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
         null;
       }
      else {
         $before = wc_get_product( $post_id )->gallery_image_ids;
      }

      if($previous_product_id === $post_id) {
         $images_to_be_deleted = array_diff($before, $after);
            foreach($images_to_be_deleted as $delete) {
               wp_delete_attachment( $delete, $force_delete = true );
            }
      }
      $previous_product_id = $post_id;
      }
}
```